# Winforms - how to disable focusing of everything inside of a main form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a very simple winforms application, with only this inside:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "cmd.exe", UseShellExecute = true };
        var process = Process.Start(info);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
    }
}
```

Now, I need to make it, so that everything that is inside of Form1 would not be able to gain any focus at all. I thought about putting some transparent control over everything inside, but then that control would gain focus. Also I have no idea which control would I use for that and how to get this transparent control on top of everything inside of Form1.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You could try `this.Enabled = false;`

Comment: Sounds like an XY question.  The simple way is to use another plain Form with nothing worth focusing, display it with ShowDialog() and use *that* as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `Panel` subclass (`NonFocusablePanel`) and do something like so:

```
class NonFocusablePanel : Panel
{
  static readonly uint WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
  {
    // Ignore focus
    if(msg.Msg == WM_SETFOCUS)
      return;

    base.WndProc(ref msg);
  }
}
```

Then place this panel on your `Form`, with its `Dock` set to `Fill` (and `BackColor` as `Transparent`).

On `Form_Load` you could initially hide it and bring it to the front (`ZIndex`) so it is on top of all other controls:

```
panel.Hide();
panel.BringToFront();
```

Then when you want to show it...

```
panel.Show();
```

Comment: Have you maybe tried using your solution with my code? Because your solution looks pretty nice, but I couldn't make it work, the command window that I have inside of my form is still focusable. :/

Comment: I will try later, don't have VS with me at the moment.